# dbutils.widget in DATABRICKS input and output

Tags: scala, databricks

I am using dbutils.widgets.dropdown in one notebook, XYZ.

```
 dbutils.widgets.dropdown("user", "user1", Seq("user1", "user2"), "User Name") 
  user = dbutils.widgets.get("user")
```

However I would like to pass 'user' into another notebook, ABC as input string

Would like to know how to do ?

Thank you